# When voting to close a question, can the automatically added comment be made immediately visible to the voter?

Tags: feature-request, comments, vote-to-close

When you vote to close a question, certain reasons generate a comment, e.g. closing as a duplicate generates a comment "possible duplicate of ...".

This comment doesn't show up on the question straight away after the popup with closing reasons is closed. This sometimes confuses me as I forget that a comment was to be added automatically and add a manual one too.

Can the comments section be refreshed automatically so that I can see the comment added straight away?

Comment: Good find, @gparyani

Comment: I didn't notice the other question too and it was asked only few days ago!

Comment: Different key words, that's all. Don't feel too bad @Szymon :)